# python vk api не работает генератор ссылки на фото

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Вот основной код

```py
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import vk_api
import random
from datetime import datetime
import time
import get_pictures

token = ""
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
#While True здесь оказался не нужен. Его функцию выполняет for event in longpoll.listen(): Спасибо подписчику за это уточнение.

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        print('Сообщение пришло в: ' + str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%H:%M:%S")))
        print('Текст сообщения: ' + str(event.text))
        response = str.lower(event.text)
        print (response, event.user_id)
        if event.from_user and not (event.from_me):
            if response == 'начать':
                vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': 'Ну привет', 'random_id':0 })
                vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': 'Может ты что то хочешь узнать?', 'random_id':0 })
            elif response == '':
                attachment = ''
                vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': 'Лови ', 'random_id':0, 'attachment' : attachment  })
            else:
                vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': 'Пока работает только функция \"Начать\"', 'random_id':0 })
```

Вот код к которому основной обращается в процессе выполнения

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random
import time

def get(vk_session, id_group,vk):
    try:
        attachment = ''
        # print('До всего '+str(time.ctime(time.time())))
        max_num = vk.photos.get(owner_id=id_group, album_id='wall', count=0)['count']
        # print('Смотрим время после получения количества всех картинок ' + str(time.ctime(time.time())))
        num = random.randint(1, max_num)
        # print('Время до получения пикчи ' + str(time.ctime(time.time())))
        pictures = vk.photos.get(owner_id=str(id_group), album_id='wall', count=5, offset=num)['items']
        buf = []
        for element in pictures:
            buf.append('photo' + str(id_group) + '_' + str(element['id']))
        print(buf)
        attachment = ','.join(buf)
        print(type(attachment))
        # print('Время после получения пикчи '+str(time.ctime(time.time())))
        print(attachment)
        return attachment
    except:
        return get(vk_session, id_group, vk)
```

Тут всего два условия если создать ситуацию когда выполнняется 1 условие, то есть в сообщения группе написать "1", то всё работает, бот отвечает, но второе условие, то если боту написать цифру "2", он перестает функционировать, во втором файле к которму отсылается первый функция которая создает ссылки на фото, и мне кажется я там что то не так сделал.

Цель: при отправке в сообщения группе цифру 2 бот должен писать слово "Лови" и отправлять 3 фото с какой либо группы

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Исправил недочет